# What is the process of obtaining Var(βhat) in simple linear regression?

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-model

I have just started statistics and we have used the estimation strategy OLS to obtain the parameter estimate of the independent variable for a simple linear regression model. As I understand it, my statistical software has used data from one single sample to compute fitted values for the model. But recently we have been doing hypothesis testing, in which we use terms such as Var(βhat). **I am confused as to how we are able to obtain the variance of βhat** if we only have one set of fitted values. To find Var(βhat) do we have to conduct OLS on some more samples to generate more fitted values of β and then we look at all the different values that βhat took on and from this equate its variance? If this is the case, how many estimates of β (or how many "versions" of βhat) should we have so that our inference testing is accurate?

Comment: Notation differs from text to text. To be sure you get the answer you want, please write the regression model using your notation for slope, intercept, and error,

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, var(beta) refers to an estimation of the variance of beta itself.
We dont need many samples to get a sample of estimated betas so can compute the variance.

There is a formulat in regression thats hepls get the estimate of the variance of beta so can be able to compute our quadratic error (bias**2 +VAR) of the estimator so we can see if its accurate or no. Check books about regression to understand.

Look for #statistical_learning book its amazing.
If you need more details comment on the answer